# .NET Core Global To and Self Contained exe

Tags: c#, command-line-interface, .net-core-2.2

I am creating an exe that I want to have as a 'dotnetcore global tool' and also as a stand-alone exe.  This is what my csproj looks like:

```
  <PropertyGroup>
    <OutputType>Exe</OutputType>
    <TargetFramework>netcoreapp2.2</TargetFramework>
    <LangVersion>7.1</LangVersion>
    <CopyLocalLockFileAssemblies>true</CopyLocalLockFileAssemblies>
    <PlatformTarget>AnyCPU</PlatformTarget>
    <TargetLatestRuntimePatch>true</TargetLatestRuntimePatch>
    <PackAsTool>true</PackAsTool>
    <IsPackable>true</IsPackable>
    <ToolCommandName>HostRunner</ToolCommandName>
    <PackageOutputPath>./nupkg</PackageOutputPath>
    <AssemblyName>HostRunner</AssemblyName>
  </PropertyGroup>
```

I can run `dotnet pack` no problem, but when I run

```
dotnet publish my.csproj -r=win10-x64 -c=Debug --self-contained
```

I get an error saying `error NETSDK1053: Pack as tool does not support self contained.`

What am I doing wrong?!

Answer (score 1):

You need two csprojs. One for the nuget package and one for the exe. Make the exe one use the nuget package one.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into the same issue.
I'm using a separate property group defined like this:

```xml
<PropertyGroup Condition="$(TargetFramework) != 'net462'">
    <PackAsTool>true</PackAsTool>
    <ToolCommandName>my-command</ToolCommandName>
    <PackageOutputPath>./nupkg</PackageOutputPath>
</PropertyGroup>
```

Comment: Can you explain what "$(RuntimeIdentifier) == ''" does?

Answer (score -2):

Same issue here, found a [reply on GitHub](https://github.com/dotnet/cli/issues/10607#issuecomment-454528443)

just removed the directive

```
<PackAsTool>true</PackAsTool>
```

in the .csproj file, it just worked like before.